# Naming Admin Menus and Submenus

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu

I'm building a plugin that requires its own set of admin pages. I know how to create the top-level link and how to add sub-menus to it. However, what seems to happen is when I create the top-level link, it also automatically adds a submenu page of the same name if I add another submenu page to it.

I'm simply looking for a way to change the name of my first submenu page so that it is different from the parent name. (i.e. in the admin panel, expanding the "Links" menu shows an "All Links" submenu page. Mine would instead say "Links" on top and then "Links" instead of "All Links")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have set the name of the `$menu_slug` exactly the same as the parent slug.

Comment: Ok, but if I create a top level menu and I'm trying to add submenus to it, WordPress seems to automatically create a new submenu that corresponds to the top level menu name (So there is no submenu to start with, but if I decide to use `add_submenu_page` and add a new submenu, I get a submenu named the same as the top level and THEN the submenu I just created). Is there somewhere in the `add_menu_page()` function call where I can specify the name I'd want to give to that automatically created submenu?

Comment: Afai-remember: You have to "play" with the names of the slugs. I don't know exactly at the second, but you have to name both equal (on different args) to _not_ get the double menu entry.

Comment: Ok, so I'm playing with it-- looking at the documentation for the `add_menu_page` function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page.

So the parameters of this function:
$page_title - changes the title of the title page (equivalent to typing the title in <title></title>);
$menu_title - changes the on-screen name text for the menu, but changes both the top-level and the automatically created submenu;
$capability - permissions requirement;
$menu_slug - unique slug requirement to be used in the page URL;

Are you saying I need to do something with `add_submenu_page` as well?

Comment: Try it with `$menu_slug` set equal both for parent & child.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks a ton! That little thing was reaaaally bothering me.

Comment: n/p. Took me a long time too when I searched it :)

Answer (score -1):

This is how I solved the parent menu item also being listed as a submenu item:

```
    if(!function_exists('remove_submenu_page')) {
      unset($GLOBALS['submenu']['parent_menu_slug'][0]);
    }
    else {
      remove_submenu_page('parent_menu_slug','submenu_slug');
    }
```